# htaccess error 404 handling not working + dynamic 404 error page?

Tags: .htaccess, errordocument

First of all, my ErrorDocument 404 /v1 is never redirecting, but if I look in the Chrome Inspector, I really have a 404 error. At first I thought it was because I really needed to specify a file ex: error.html, but that didn't work either. /v1 is just a wordpress subdomain, and I want to redirect all of my errors there. /v1 falls on my homepage of my subdomain.

Also I would like to make the error page dynamic, but I can't figure how to do that. Something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public_html/(.*)
ErrorDocument 404 /v1/%1
```

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're goinmg to need to return the 404 through a php script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.php?path=$1 [L]
```

And in the `404.php file`:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

print('The file that you requested: ' . $_GET['path'] . ' was not found\n');

// or include a special 404 page

include ('/path/to/' . $_GET['path']);
?>
```

Or you could lose the `?path=$1` part completely and just look in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

**This syntax is incorrect**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public_html/(.*)
ErrorDocument 404 /v1/%1
```

Because `ErrorDocument` has no connection with `RewriteCond` (mod_rewrite) and it is unconditional.

**Conditional 404 handling example:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^foo/ - [L,NC,R=404]
```

Comment: Error 404 / does no redirection to my root, I can still see the 404 error in my Chrome Inspector, I"m really wondering why it's not working...

Comment: There are ways to do conditional 404, I will edit my answer to show you how. Also try it out in a different browser.

Comment: Very nice, but can you explain a little bit please? I know L is for last and NC means not to care about caps. Is R=404 to check if it's an 404 error?

Comment: `R=404` means return http status 404 for given condition and that will be handled by `ErrorDocument 404`

Comment: But the error page is always the same. I would like the error page to change with each page :/.

Comment: Hmm I need to think about that, its pretty late here, I will come back to this answer in the morning.

Comment: Looks like @JonLin has answered to your problem, see if that satisfies you. Though keep in mind that browser will not get status=404 in response which would be the case with `ErrorDocument 404` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I use this syntax! Usually works!

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<script>window.location.href='404.php?page='+window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1];</script>"
```